# Change file name on upload in Media Page

Tags: uploads

I trying to program the following rules:

1. When attachment uploaded on wp-admin/post.php page, on the act of uploading, rename it to `{post-slug}-{n}-[WxH].{ext}`
2. When attachment uploaded on wp-admin/upload.php page, on the act of uploading, rename it to `{site-name}-{n}-[WxH].{ext}`

Where `{n}` is the numerical order, `[WxH]` the sizes applied by WordPress and `{ext}` its extension.

Item 1 I got with `add_attachment` hook. How can I achieve item 2? How to change the name of a file uploaded on Media Page on the act of uploading?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this might be to attach a custom field to each post to keep the increment {n}.

Something to the effect of:

```
$attach_inc = 1;

if ( is_single() ) {
    if ( $attach_inc = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'attachment_inc', true ) ) {
        $attach_inc++;
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'attachment_inc', $attach_inc );
    } else {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'attachment_inc', $attach_inc );
    }
} else {
    if ( $attach_inc = get_option( 'attachment_inc' ) ) {
        $attach_inc++;
        set_option( 'attachment_inc', $attach_inc );
    } else {
        add_option( 'attachment_inc', $attach_inc );
    }
}

// DO YOUR ADD ATTACHMENT STUFF HERE
```

Comment: Thanks, socki03, the incrementing part I'm gonna solve creating a meta field for the post and a config fild for the site, but the problem is which action to hook.

Comment: I misunderstood your last sentence in your question then.  I thought you'd figured out how to change the name using add_attachment, so I thought you were looking for ideas how to increment attachment IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could change the filename trough [wp_handle_upload_prefilter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter). Though I'm not sure how you are going to determine if it's a post upload or media upload, maybe you can check the $post global.